# [Class]::New() causing blank line on the console

Tags: powershell, oop

I am working on implementing a singleton class to store some regularly accessed status information for my script, including hacking around the issue of `$myInvocation` only being populated in the main script. All working as planned with this.

```
class pxStatus {
    static [pxStatus] $singleton = $null
    [string]$Context = 'machine'
    [string]$Path = $null
    [datetime]$StartTime = (Get-Date)

    pxStatus ([string]$path) {
        if ([pxStatus]::singleton -eq $null) {
            $this.Path = $path
            [pxStatus]::singleton = $this
        } else {
            Throw "Singleton already initialized"
        }
    }

    static [pxStatus] Get() {
        if ([pxStatus]::singleton -eq $null) {
            Throw "Singleton not yet initialized"
        } else {
            return [pxStatus]::singleton
        }
    }
}

CLS
[void]([pxStatus]::New((Split-Path ($myInvocation.myCommand.path) -parent)))
([pxStatus]::Get()).StartTime
([pxStatus]::Get()).Context
([pxStatus]::Get()).Path
```

With one exception. Even with that [void] on the `[pxStatus]::New()` line, I am getting a blank line in the console. Even `$null = ([pxStatus]::New((Split-Path ($myInvocation.myCommand.path) -parent)))` is echoing a blank line to the console. And for the life of me I can't see what is causing it.

Comment: And when using `| Out-Null` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not `new` that causes a blank line but `([pxStatus]::Get()).StartTime`.

To fix the issue, you may output it as string, i.e. not formatted, e.g. `([pxStatus]::Get()).StartTime.ToString()`

Comment: Aha! I should have thought to rem each of the Get lines and see if anything changed!

Answer (score 1):

You problem [has already been diagnosed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60928586/712649), but I wanted to take a second to show how to *actually* implement a singleton-*like* type in PowerShell (see inline comments):

```
class pxStatus {

    # hide backing field from user
    hidden static [pxStatus] $singleton = $null

    [string]$Context = 'machine'
    [string]$Path = $null
    [datetime]$StartTime = (Get-Date)

    # hide instance constructor, no one should call this directly
    hidden pxStatus ([string]$path) {
        # Only allow to run if singleton instance doesn't exist already
        if ($null -eq [pxStatus]::singleton) {
            $this.Path = $path
        } else {
            Throw "Singleton already initialized - use [pxStatus]::Get()"
        }
    }

    # Use a static constructor to initialize singleton
    # guaranteed to only run once, before [pxStatus]::Get() or [pxStatus]::singleton
    static pxStatus () {
        # grab the path from context, don't rely on user input
        if(-not $PSScriptRoot){
            throw "[pxStatus] can only be used in scripts!"
        }
        # this will only succeed once anyway
        [pxStatus]::singleton = [pxStatus]::new($PSScriptRoot)
    }

    static [pxStatus] Get() {
        # No need to (double-)check ::singleton, static ctor will have run already
        return [pxStatus]::singleton
    }
}

[pxStatus]::Get().StartTime
```

Comment: @mathias-r-jessen SOOO many birds with this one stone. I didn't know about `$PSScriptRoot`, and this implementation is obviously much more elegant. Woot!

Comment: @mathias-r-jessen Of course, now I need to do some reading on static constructors, since that's new to me. The hidden stuff should have been obvious, and maybe in a year or two it will be. Still lots I need to learn. :)